# Convert nonuniform cell array to numeric array

Tags: matlab

I am using `xlsread` in MATLAB to read in sheets from an excel file. My goal is to have each column of the excel sheet read as a numeric array. One of the columns has a mix of numbers and numbers+char.  For example, the values could be 200, 300A, 450, 500A, 200A, 100.  here is what I have so far:

```
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread(fileIn, sheets{ii});    % Reading in each sheet from a for loop
myCol = raw(:, 4)                             % I want all rows of column 4
for kk=1:numel(myCol)
       if iscellstr(myCol(kk))
           myCol(kk) = (cellfun(@(x)strrep(x, 'A', ''), myCol(kk), 'UniformOutput', false));
       end
end

myCol = cell2mat(myCol);
```

This is able to strip off the char from the number but then I am left with:

```
myCol = 

[200]

'300'

[450]

'500'

'200'

[100]
```

which errors out on `cell2mat` with:

> cell2mat(myCol)
>
> ??? Error using ==> cell2mat at 46
>
> All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

I feel like I am probably mixing up `()` and `{}` somewhere.  Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is the variable `alt`? Should that be `myCol`?

Comment: Whoops sorry.  Yes it should be. I edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start from reading the file

```
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread('test.xlsx');
myCol = raw(:, 4);

idx = cellfun(@ischar,myCol ); %# find strings
data = zeros(size(myCol)); %# preallocate matrix for numeric data
data(~idx) = cell2mat(myCol(~idx)); %# convert numeric data
data(idx) = str2double(regexprep(myCol(idx),'\D','')); %# remove non-digits and convert to numeric
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `myCol` is initially a cell array containing both numbers and strings, something like this in your example:

```
myCol = {200; '300A'; 450; '500A'; '200A'; 100};
```

The steps you have to follow to convert the string entries into numeric values is:

1. Identify the cell entries in `myCol` that are strings. You can use a loop to do this, as in your example, or you can use the function [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to get a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) like so:

   ```
   index = cellfun(@ischar,myCol);
   ```
2. Remove the letters. If you know the letters to remove will always be `'A'`, as in your example, you can use a simple function like [STRREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html) on all of your indexed cells like so:

   ```
   strrep(myCol(index),'A','')
   ```

   If you can have all sorts of other characters and letters in the string, then a function like [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) may work better for you. For your example, you could do this:

   ```
   regexprep(myCol(index),'\D','')
   ```
3. Convert the strings of numbers to numeric values. You can do this for all of your indexed cells using the function [STR2DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2double.html):

   ```
   str2double(regexprep(myCol(index),'\D',''))
   ```

The final result of the above can then be combined with the original numeric values in `myCol`. Putting it all together, you get the following:

```
>> index = cellfun(@ischar,myCol);
>> result(index,1) = str2double(regexprep(myCol(index),'\D',''));
>> result(~index) = [myCol{~index}]

result =

   200
   300
   450
   500
   200
   100
```